# SignalR 2.0 + Azure service bus backplane delay

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub, servicebus, azureservicebus

We are writing a test chat application using the Azure service bus backplane.  We have stripped it down to barebones but there are pockets of "lag" where messages sent don't get received for up to 15 seconds later.

Startup.cs

```
string connectionString = GetServiceBusConnectionString();
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(connectionString, "Chat");  

app.MapSignalR();
```

Chathub.cs

```
protected void MsgAll(User user, string content)
{
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage(new Message() { Content = content, NickName = user.NickName, Status = user.Status, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now });
}
```

Chat.js

```
self.chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (res) {
    self.messages.push(new messageItem(res));
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("chat-messages");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
};
```

It works fine when its standalone, but starts lagging intermittently when we add the backplane, even on one server.  Any tips/help appreciated.

Additional info:

- using defaults
- Looking at mgmt portal we see 5 topics created

Comment: We're experiencing the same issues. 10-20 sec delays on calls that result in using the service bus backplane. Did you ever learn more about this?